# Mapping model to control using Ajax post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to map my form that contains the filters to my view model but when the ajax post is sent the controller object is empty.

This my view model

```
public class FilterViewModel
{
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public List<Filter> Filters { get; set; }
}

public class Filter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FilterName { get; set; }
    public List<Facet> Facets { get; set; }
}

public class Facet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index([FromBody] FilterViewModel filterViewModel)
        {
            var auxFilters = filterViewModel;
            try
            {
                if (auxFilters != null)
                {
                    return Json(new
                    {
                        msg = "Successfully parsed filters"
                    }); ;
                }
                else
                {
                    return Json(new
                    {
                        msg = "Object is empty"
                    }); ;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

This my razor page

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 container-fluid">
                <form asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Overview" method="post" id="formfilter">
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.GroupName" />
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Filters.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <article class="card-group-item">
                            <header class="card-header">
                                <label asp-for="@Model.Filters[i].Name">@Model.Filters[i].Name</label>
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Filters[i].Id" />
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Filters[i].FilterName" />
                            </header>
                            <div class="filter-content">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    @for (int j = 0; j < Model.Filters[i].Facets.Count; j++)
                                    {
                                        <label class="form-check">
                                            <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Filters[i].Facets[j].Selected" id="facetcheck">
                                            <label asp-for="@Model.Filters[i].Facets[j].Selected">@Model.Filters[i].Facets[j].Value</label>
                                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Filters[i].Facets[j].Id" />
                                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Filters[i].Facets[j].Value" />
                                        </label>
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    }
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Filter" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

@section Scripts
{
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input:checkbox').click(function() {
            if(this.checked) {
                 $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/Overview/Index",
                            data: $('form#formfilter').serialize(),
                            dataType: "json",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            success: function (data)
                            {
                            alert(data);
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

The mapping works perfectly when using a submit button, but I want to filter as soon as someone clicks the checkbox. Therefor I am trying to make the logic of calling the controller whenever someone checks a filter

Any ideas of how to properly map my entity

Comment: What is the problem? Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace **[FromBody]** attribute with the **[FromForm]** attribute.
And then, in the ajax query, remove the **content-type:"application/json"** statement. It works for me well.

Comment: Thanks alot, also removed the dataType: "json" and now it works

Comment: You`re welcome. The datatype property represents the response type. therefore, its presence should not affect the result, i think.